# Error after submitting data using <h:selectManyMenu> in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:selectManyMenu style="height:70px" value="#{bookBean.selectedBook}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{bookBean.books}"/>
</h:selectManyMenu>

<h:commandButton action="#{bookBean.doClick}" value="Submit" />
```

**BookBean.java**

```
List<SelectItem> books = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

public List<SelectItem> getBooks() {
 return books;
}
```

So, the problem is after I choose multiple items in the ManyMenu list and click the commandButton in xhtml file, it gives an error. It says "Target model Type is no a Collection or Array"

What does that mean? I need to change List<> to any collection type?

The page suppose to display the items I selected in the first page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
value="#{bookBean.selectedBook}">
```

has to be a collection.

Think about it, you are selecting many items, so you have to store them in a collection. Even if you are selecting one SelectItem then it has to be stored in a collection as well.

So, make sure .selectedBook is a collection.
Regards!

Comment: And rename it to `selectedBooks`.

Comment: by collection, do you mean HashMap? I'm having trouble converting it though.

Comment: Hashmap is not a Collection technically because it does not extend Collection interface. But an ArrayList should work. Similar to what you have for "books" Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already made it to be ArrayList. Now I have to make a Collection out of it. What do you mean by _making sure .selectedBooks is a collection_?

So this is what my BookFacade.java class look like:
`public class BookFacade {

private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

public BookFacade() {
   books.add(new Book(1, "Book 1"));
   books.add(new Book(2, "Book 2"));
   books.add(new Book(3, "Book 3"));
   books.add(new Book(4, "Book 4"));
}`

What else do I have to add? Thanks. :)

Comment: What is the type of "selectedBook" in your backing bean?

Comment: This is the problem. This needs to be a List<Book> selectedBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5067/discussion-between-amnbhrm-and-mechkov)